# Defining bind variable in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, bind-variables

Please help me to create a bind variable

I'm doing like this

```
SELECT Period FROM POWER WHERE Period = :F1;

EXEC :F;
```

Result: Shows Null Values.

Period column is of Date datatype.

Comment: Where are you running this? SQL*Plus / Toad / somewhere else?

Comment: you have to init F1. declare it, give it a value. if you want to be prompted for a value, use a IDE like SQL Developer. you'll get prompted in SQL*Plus if you use &F1 - but that's not a bind.

Comment: If you are using SQL*Plus, there are a number of posts that address bind variable usage.  I really like Alex Poole's answer with this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737849/declare-bind-variables-in-sqlplus.

Comment: Thanks *8-) The syntax in that answer works in SQL Developer too. Not sure about other clients. In this case you should also have an explicit `to_date()` around the bind variable, which will be a string, and specify the expected format.

Comment: @Boneist, I'm using in oracle sql developer

Comment: @Ashish - the linked answer works in SQL Developer too. Has that, or any of the other answers about bind variables, solved your issue?

Comment: @AlexPoole NO alex..am still struggling with my issue.

Comment: @Ashish - then you'll need to edit your question to explain what you are trying and why it isn't working for you. As written it looks like a pretty good match. I'm not sure what the `exec` is doing though; you can't use a bind variable for an entire PL/SQL statement. Include what you want the bind values to be set to an what you'll do with the and the results.