# How bind variable is different from simple variable in plsql? what are their application?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
 variable deptno number ;   
          deptno1 number;
```

Comment: In terms of declaration there is no difference. It's the way you use it. Every Pl/SQL variable referenced in a static SQL statement inside a PL/SQL block is a bind variable. In case of dynamic SQL (native dynamic SQL for example `execute immediate`) you'd use `using` clause to bind a variable which allows the SQL engine avoid hard parse  of the statement every time you change the value of your variable.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was your question really... However, I hope, The following answer/ post (from Alex Poole) should give you a fair idea how to define a variable in SQL /PL-SQL and how.

[Declare bind variables in SQL*Plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737849/declare-bind-variables-in-sqlplus)

We try to 'bind' them in both ways and avoid literals.

Answer (score 0):

A bind variable is part of the interface between SQL and the calling application or host language, so if your 'simple variable in PL/SQL' is not used in a SQL statement then it isn't a bind variable :)

```
declare
    msg varchar2(100) := 'Hello';
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(msg);
end;
```

In the case of actual bind variables, these are identical whatever way you do it. The PL/SQL compiler just builds the code for you behind the scenes.

Plain PL/SQL:

```
declare
    l_dummy varchar2(1) := 'X';
    l_result integer;
begin
    select count(*) into l_result from dual where dummy = l_dummy;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_result);
end;
```

Bind variable explicitly defined in SQL*Plus:

```
var dummy varchar2(1)

exec :dummy := 'X'

declare
    l_result integer;
begin
    select count(*) into l_result from dual where dummy = :dummy;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_result);
end;
```

Either way you will see from v$sql, dbms_xplan etc that the SQL it actually executed was

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DUAL WHERE DUMMY = :B1
```

Answer (score -2):

The main difference is performance-wise. Bind variables can be used to parse a query once and save future parses every time you run the query with different values.
Using regular variables forces Oracle to do a hard parse every time the value of the variables change.

Comment: That's not true at all. A statement such as `update table1 set col1 = v_col1;` doesn't cause a hard parse each time the value of v_col1 changes. That's because it's treated as a bind variable. If you were to do `execute immediate 'update table1 set col1 = '||v_col1;` then you're forcing the database to run a statement where the value is hardcoded - i.e. it's running `update table1 set col1 = 101` if v_col1 = 101 and `update table1 set col1 = 102` if v_col1 = 102, etc. I think you've confused the two concepts.