# how to write parametrised query in oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle, testing

I have a basic requirement where I need to query database multiple time with same parameters
i.e

```
Select * from Table1 where ID1 in (1,2,3,4,5) ;
Select * from Table2 where ID2 in (1,2,3,4,5) ;
Select * from Table3 where ID3 in (1,2,3,4,5) ;
Select * from Table4 where ID4 in (1,2,3,4,5) ;
Select * from Table5 where ID5 in (1,2,3,4,5) ;
```

Here I want something where I can declare variables and assign the values 1,2,3,4,5 and instead of changing the value again just need to change the variable values.

something like ..

```
Select * from Table1 where ID1 in (x,y,z,a,b);
```

it may turn up a very basic questions for you but can save my lot of rework.

Comment: What are you using to execute these queries? Without defining what you're using (eg which query tool, or which programming language, etc) this is far too broad to answer properly.

Comment: Hey, I am using SQL developer to simply query the oracle db where my requirement is to compare the rows in each table for given values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL*Developer, write them as bind variables, like this (for example):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM dba_objects WHERE rownum <= :v1;

SELECT count(*) FROM dba_tab_columns WHERE rownum <= :v1;
```

In your particular case, it might be:

```
Select * from Table1 where ID1 in (:x,:y,:z,:a,:b);
```

SQL*Developer will see the colon and recognize a bind variable and prompt you for the value.

It will remember the value the next time it sees it, even in a different query.  It will still prompt you each time, but the last value you used will be filled in.

If you want to specify the variable values programmatically, you can use this:

```
VARIABLE var1 NUMBER;

exec :var1 := 15;

SELECT count(*) FROM dba_objects WHERE rownum <= :var1;

SELECT count(*) FROM dba_views WHERE rownum <= :var1;
```

... but then you need to run it as script in SQL*Developer (F5 key).

Comment: sorry for silly question but can't be assign value to x like define x = 1; ??

Comment: @ErrorHunter You can, yes - see this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737849/declare-bind-variables-in-sqlplus

Answer (score 2):

I think you are probably looking for something like this

```
Select 
   * 
from Table1 
where ID1 in ('" & variable1 & "', '" & variable2 & "' ) ;
```

Comment: yes , something similar ..how to define these variables in sql developer and can we use the variable across  workspace ?

Comment: I think You would need a programming language to define the variables, unless The answer above shared by Mathew is what you are looking for.

Comment: a simple script example can help me